# How to vertically align <li> elements in <ul>?

Tags: css

I have a horizontal `<ul>` and I need to center each `<li>` in it vertically. My markup is below. Each `<li>` has a border, and I need the items as well as their contents to be in the middle vertically. Please help; I am new to CSS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .toolbar li
        {
            border: solid 1px black;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 10px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .toolbar li.button
        {
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">first item<br />
                first item<br />
                first item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">last item</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#">button<br />
                button</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp - i know this has been answered but in case anyone looks at this from now on i found this helpful

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I assume that since you're using an XML declaration, you're not worrying about IE or older browsers.

So you can use `display:table-cell` and `display:table-row` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .toolbar ul {
            display:table-row;
        }
        .toolbar ul li
        {
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 10px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .toolbar ul li a {
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height:100px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        .toolbar ul li.button a {
            height:50px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">first item<br />
                first item<br />
                first item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">last item</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#">button<br />
                button</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, this partially works. that is, the contents of the back boxes are centered, but how do i center the boxes themselves?

Comment: no, no, the middle of the list. in this particular example, the last box should be lower than the first three.

Comment: @akonsu - I changed it, though I didn't test it on anything other than FireFox. Let me know if it fits.

Comment: Richard, thanks a lot for your help. i did not know about these display types. unfortunately they are not supported in IE7. i found a way to align the contents of each <li>: http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/vertical-aligned-nav-list.html but there seems to be no cross browser way to align <li> inside <ul>...

Comment: If you're targetting IE7, why do you have an `<?xml?>` declaration? All versions of IE do not really supoprt XHTML. I think you might need to read Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful: http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Comment: display: table is meant for tables. This is a work-around.

Answer (score 91):

Here's a good one:

Set `line-height` equal to whatever the `height` is; works like a charm!

E.g:

```
li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with a small example?

Comment: Perfect - line-height: 30px; on floated <li>'s was what I needed (Chrome)

Comment: What happens if it lays into two lines?

Comment: Yes, viable only with no more than one line of text.

Comment: This is the only thing worked for me. Other answers didn't work.

Answer (score 55):

You can use flexbox for this.

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

A detailed explanation of how to use flexbox can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Try this.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">AnaSayfa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">İletişim</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

nav {
    background-color: #9900CC;
    height: 80px;
    width: 400px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li a {
    width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```