# Need help styling this list

Tags: css, wordpress, list

I'm styling a list of recent posts and images from a plugin from wordpress. I know there is a wordpress section but my question is to just get some advice as how to style this list.

[The website is here](http://ambergoodwin.com/averylawoffice/averytest)

This is what it looks like now.

[image]

This is my CSS

```
.advanced-recent-posts { 
        list-style-type: none; 
    }

    .advanced-recent-posts li { 
        font-size: .7em; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        line-height: 20px; 
        color: #761616; 
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase; 
        width: 250px; 
        position: relative; 
        top: -35px; 
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .advanced-recent-posts li a {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .advanced-recent-posts li img {
        position: relative; 
        top: 0px; 
        left: -10px; 
        padding: 5px; 
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }
```

and so far so good. But because both the image and the title & date are in the some

They move together which is not what I want, but because it is a plugin I dont know how to change that. So I was hoping with the provided website and CSS that someone could help me just make that second line of each recent post follow directly under the first. Like in my design here.

[image]

@Bonjour: This is what I got doing the

```
.advanced-recent-posts li { display:table-row; vertical-align:top;}
```

(and of course with all the other styling I had on it)

[image]

The post titles are at least flowing right.

Comment: Does this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul

Comment: I'll have to take a look through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some weird positioning going on there. Anyway, there are two ways to make this happen:

1. Float the image left, add a bit of right/bottom padding. This way text naturally flows under the image
2. Take advantage of the relative positioning on the `li` and set `position:absolute` on the image, while giving the `li` enough padding to move the text from under it. This way text will never flow under the image

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/Ucrsk/

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the style of the anchor ie.

```
.advanced-recent-posts li a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. No luck though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate from my comment in your question, try using:

```
li {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**OR**

```
li {
    display:table-row;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: See my edit on my question above. I used the display: table-row and it kinda works, I just need to get the post titles over now.

Comment: Try adding <img src="" **align="left"** /> - not sure how reliant you are on CSS for these images but I've often found that this does the trick. Just add some padding to it.

Comment: That didn't work, however I was able to figure it out with the help of another answer. Thanks a lot for your time!