# vertical-align within an <li> tag

Tags: html, css, navbar

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">
 <div id="container">
  <ul style="height:40px">
    <li><p id="navtext">Home</p></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li {
    float:left;
}
#navtext {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom:-50px;
}
#navbar {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#3498db;
}
#container {
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-left:15%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I would like to have the "Home" text centered within the `<ul>` tag that is 40px tall. I have tried looking around for an answer but nothing I try seems to work. I'm trying to make a navbar for my site.

Comment: `li, li > p { line-height: 40px; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align <li> elements in <ul>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your css:

```
#container ul li {line-height:10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PWTcL/

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single line, use `line-height: 40px`, and remove `margin` on `<p>` :

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li {
    float:left;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.navtext {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom:-50px;
}
#navbar {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#3498db;
}
#container {
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-left:15%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
 <div id="container">
  <ul style="height:40px">
    <li><p class="navtext">Home</p></li>
    <li><p class="navtext">Link</p></li>
    <li><p class="navtext">Contact</p></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
li {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}
#navtext {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom:-50px;    
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdJj6/)