# Vertically align two ULs

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get my responsive navbar styled up but I'm stuck at **vertically align elements**.

Here's the navbar HTML :

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li>
            <form method="post">
                <label>
                    <input type="text" autofocus>
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a class="button" href="#">Publish</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvUP5/2/)

I already tried to vertically align my elements using table display from this thread : [How to vertically align <li> elements in <ul>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul). It works well if I try to align all LIs within a UL but it doesn't work if I try to align all ULs within a DIV.

Comment: What's wrong in the fiddle? Looks OK to me.

Comment: Why are you using UL's for this? UL's are for lists, which these do not appear to be.

Comment: Right. If you need stuff like `.navbar:after {display: table;}`, you're doing it wrong. That is, you should only make things `display:table` if there are things inside it that you can make `table-row` and `table-cell`. This is an ugly kludge that happens to come out the way you want it in your browser, but is not guaranteed to work in all browsers or in all situations.