# Extra-large list disc not aligned vertically in the middle

Tags: html, css, list

I have a simple unordered list with discs as `list-type`. I want to make the disc large so I enlarged the font-size of the `ul`. However, now the disc is not aligned in the middle vertically with the text.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

[**SEE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7rzguw1/)

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

ul  {list-style: disc;font-size: 260%;}
a   {font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 40px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
     border:1px solid green}
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use psedo-element `before`:

```
.stops      {}
.stops ul   {list-style-type: none;}
.stops li   {}
.stops a        {font-size: 16px;
line-height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
border:1px solid green}
li:before {content:"·";font-size:120px;vertical-align:middle;line-height:20px;}
```

Don't have to use `list-style: disc` but `content:"."` and adjust the font size to looks like large disc.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7rzguw1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix for this. Just add `position:relative` property.

```
a {
    position:relative;
    top:-7px;
}
```