# How do center an image vertically within LI

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srasve8e/

HTML:

```
<div class="dvMain">
        <ul class="ulMM specClear">
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">FORUM</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mmTrigger"><img src="nav-icon.png" class="imgMenu" /></div>
    </div>
```

I want to put image on left of each sub menu but the image keeps going top-align.

Please help me center the image vertically. I tried vertical-align but that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul

Comment: What is the purpose of getting multiple accounts on SO: `SiKni8, Suchit Kumar & SearchForKnowledge`, seriously?! Did i miss some?

Comment: @A.Wolff Multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose the image has dimensions 20px by 20px then style the image as

```
.image
{
position : absolute;
top : 50%;
margin-top : -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will probably be better off using **Flex**. You could replace all floats and JS height hacks with Flex quite easily, once you familiarise yourself with it. In your case:

```
.dvMain {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Plus **remove floats and switch the order of ul and img**:

```
<div class="dvMain">
  <div id="mmTrigger"><img src="nav-icon.png" class="imgMenu" /></div>
  <ul class="ulMM specClear">
    <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li class="liMM"><a href="#" class="mmLink">FORUM</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can (should) also try and remove everything unnecessary, your code seems a bit convoluted.

**[This](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html)** is a cheatsheet I use almost daily, you can pick it up quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could use a position the image manually by adding margin and paddings. However I think that the example here is a clean way to have an image on left of each sub menu that is centered aligned.

```
<style>
        #test {  list-style-image: url(images/bullet.gif); }
    </style>

    <ul id="test">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
```