# how to get text aligned vertically with text in list using css

Tags: html, css

I am using a background image of a check for my list. The problem is that for some reason text that runs onto the next line for a list item does not align with the text above it, but rather the check image. I have tried using `list-style-position: outside;` but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-indent: 1.2em;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/15x15);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.checklist-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.checklist-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checklist-left">
  <li>Improve clarity</li>
  <li>Check formatting</li>
  <li>Improve logical flow</li>
</ul>
<ul class="checklist-right">
  <li>Eliminate irrelevant words</li>
  <li>Verify adherence to stylistic guidelines</li>
</ul>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi @chell, here is another person who had the same problem as you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `text-indent` which will only adjust the first line of text.

> The text-indent property specifies how much horizontal space should be left before the beginning of the first line of the text content of an element.

*text-indent (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)*

To fix, make the following modifications to your CSS:

- Remove `text-indent: 1.2em;` from `li`
- Add `padding-left: 1.2em;` to `li`

This will apply the `padding` to the whole left side of the `li` pushing the content across and allowing the `background-image` to use blank space.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/15x15);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.checklist-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.checklist-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
/*Added to make the issue visible in the snippet*/
.checklist-left, .checklist-right {
  padding: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checklist-left">
  <li>Improve clarity</li>
  <li>Check formatting</li>
  <li>Improve logical flow</li>
</ul>
<ul class="checklist-right">
  <li>Eliminate irrelevant words</li>
  <li>Verify adherence to stylistic guidelines</li>
</ul>
```

`list-style-position` will have no effect when using a background image as it only influences the position of an actual check mark.

> The list-style-position property specifies the position of the marker box in the principal block box.

*list-style-position (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position)*

Comment: An incredibly well explained, informative and easy to implement solution. Thank you very much it works!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, instead of `list-style-type` you could use `:before` pseudo element and `content: '✔';`

```css
.lists {
  background: #154B99;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  flex: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li:before {
   content: '✔';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   font-size: 12px;
   transform: translate(-100%, 0);
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul class="checklist-left">
    <li>Improve clarity</li>
    <li>Check formatting</li>
    <li>Improve logical flow</li>
  </ul> 

  <ul class="checklist-right">
    <li> Eliminate irrelevant words</li>
    <li>Verify adherence to stylistic guidelines</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also align `li` and `:before` vertically in middle with `transform: translate(-100%, -50%);`

```css
.lists {
  background: #154B99;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  flex: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li:before {
   content: '✔';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 50%;
   font-size: 12px;
   transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul class="checklist-left">
    <li>Improve clarity</li>
    <li>Check formatting</li>
    <li>Improve logical flow</li>
  </ul> 

  <ul class="checklist-right">
    <li> Eliminate irrelevant words</li>
    <li>Verify adherence to stylistic guidelines</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```