# Why is my logo not centered in the navbar?

Tags: html, css

Here is my navbar right now (I outlined everything in black):

[image]

I want to make the logo and "About Services Contact" go in the center of the navbar vertically (not horizontally) and I don't understand how to do that and why my code hasn't made it like that already, here is my css for the navbar related stuff:

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  /* line-height: 10px; */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav div.logo {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  /* height: auto; */
  padding-left: 2rem;
  /* padding-bottom: 3rem; */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /* padding-bottom: 0px; */
}

.nav div.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;

}

.nav div.logo a:hover {
  color: #00e676;
}

.nav div.main_list {
  height: 65px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.nav div.main_list ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li {
  width: auto;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a:hover {
  color: #00e676;
}


.navTrigger {
  display: none;
}

.nav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Here is the link to the codepen in which I got the navbar from if more info on the CSS is needed, the CSS is the exact same: https://codepen.io/albizan/pen/mMWdWZ

Answer (score 0):

Just use following styles on the container:

```
<div class="container" style="display: flex;justify-content:center;">
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the navbar centered vertically, sorry I edited the question I meant in a vertical manner so that it's even on both top and bottom?

Comment: Really not sure what you mean exactly. A vertically aligned list? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul